# How to change Hibernate StandardQueryCache

Tags: hibernate, caching

Can someone tell me how can I change StandardQueryCache and StandardQueryCacheFactory with my own customized implementations. I need to change the cache rule that Hibernate uses for cache the objects. (cache objects based on a unique property other than the ID)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the solution; just use hibernate.cache.query_cache_factory in the hibernate configuration file.